# PineScript: array of const strings or how to call security() with a member of an array

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to make some sort of correlation by power study. The plan is to draw all elements of an industry, average and SPX. The industry is chosen depending on which ticker you are looking at.

I run into the problem that I can't use members of an array to call security(). I'm looking for any workaround or solution:

```
banks = array.new_string(0)
array.push(banks, "BAC")
array.push(banks, "JPM")
array.push(banks, "C")
array.push(banks, "WFC")

rocPeriod = input(30, minval = 1)
perc_change = roc(close, rocPeriod)

for i = 0 to array.size(result)
    var sec = security(array.get(result, i), res, perc_change)
```

This code doesn't work because security() expects string, but arrays get() return series[string] by some reason.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Recently discussed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629613/extracting-string-value-from-a-string-array-in-pine

Comment: The workaround could be to use multiple plots like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579897/plotting-within-a-loop-cannot-use-plot-in-local-scope-tradingview-pine-scri

Comment: running into the same problem. would like to assign various tickers to an array, ans simply look through them, retrieve their timeseries and blend together. seems very basic problem...but so difficult in pinescript. is there a solution 4 years later to this?

Comment: I need this also...